# Execute a new process or multiples in a program

Tags: c++, c

I am wondering what the best practice is for executing new processes (programs) from a running process. To be more specific, I am implementing a C/C++ job scheduler that has to run multiple binaries while communicating with them. Is `exec` or `fork` common? Or is there any library taking care of this?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: linux or OSX like operation system.

Comment: @erip They serve quite different purposes.

Comment: No, processes are created with a copy of it. They don't need syncronization but, altering data in the child does not affect the parent and viceversa.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `popen()` to spawn the processes and communicate with them.  In order to handle communication with many processes from a single parent process, use `select()` or `poll()` to multiplex the reading/writing of the file descriptors given to you by `popen()` (you can use `fileno()` to turn a `FILE*` into an integer file descriptor).

If you want a library to abstract much of this for you, I suggest libuv.  Here's a complete example program I whipped up, largely following the docs at https://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/processes.html#spawning-child-processes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <uv.h>

static void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t *buf)
{
    *buf = uv_buf_init((char*)malloc(suggested_size), suggested_size);
}

void echo_read(uv_stream_t *server, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf)
{
    if (nread == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error echo_read");
        return;
    }

    puts(buf->base);
}

static void on_exit(uv_process_t *req, int64_t exit_status, int term_signal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Process %d exited with status %" PRId64 ", signal %d\n",
            req->pid, exit_status, term_signal);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*)req, NULL);
}

int main()
{
    uv_loop_t* loop = uv_default_loop();
    const int N = 3;
    uv_pipe_t channel[N];
    uv_process_t child_req[N];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ++ii) {
        char* args[3];
        args[0] = const_cast<char*>("ls");
        args[1] = const_cast<char*>(".");
        args[2] = NULL;

        uv_pipe_init(loop, &channel[ii], 1);

        uv_stdio_container_t child_stdio[3]; // {stdin, stdout, stderr}                                                 
        child_stdio[STDIN_FILENO].flags = UV_IGNORE;
        child_stdio[STDOUT_FILENO].flags = uv_stdio_flags(UV_CREATE_PIPE | UV_WRITABLE_PIPE);
        child_stdio[STDOUT_FILENO].data.stream = (uv_stream_t*)&channel[ii];
        child_stdio[STDERR_FILENO].flags = UV_IGNORE;

        uv_process_options_t options = {};
        options.exit_cb = on_exit;
        options.file = "ls";
        options.args = args;
        options.stdio = child_stdio;
        options.stdio_count = sizeof(child_stdio) / sizeof(child_stdio[0]);

        int r;
        if ((r = uv_spawn(loop, &child_req[ii], &options))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", uv_strerror(r));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Launched process with ID %d\n", child_req[ii].pid);
            uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*)&channel[ii], alloc_buffer, echo_read);
        }
    }

    return uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

The above will spawn three copies of `ls` to print the contents of the current directory.  They all run asynchronously.

Answer (score 5):

Okay let's start..
There are few ways to create another parallel task from one task. Although I wouldn't name all of them as processes.

**Using `fork()` system call**

Now as you have already mentioned that `fork()` creates a process from your parent process. There are few good things and few bad things about `fork()`.

*Good things*

1. `fork()` is able to create a completely different process & in multi-core CPU systems, it can truly achieve parallelism
2. `fork()` also creates a child process with different `pid` & hence it is nice if you ever want to kill that process explicitly.
3. `wait()` & `waitpid()` system calls are nice to make the parent wait for child.
4. `fork` generates `SIGCHILD` signal and with `sigaction` function you can make the parent wait for child without blocking it.

*Bad things*

1. `fork` processes do not share the same address space & hence if one process is having say a variable `var`, the other process cannot access directly that same `var`. Hence communication is a big issue.
2. To communicate you need to use certain IPC mechanisms like `pipe`, `namedpipe`, `messageQueues` or `sharedMemory`
3. Now out of these `pipe`, `namedpipe` and `messageQueues` can use `read` & `write` system calls and because `read` & `write` system calls are blocking system calls, you application remains synchronized but these `IPCs` are very slow. The only fast `IPC` is `sharedMemory` but it cannot use `read` & `write` & hence you need to use your own synchronization mechanisms, like `semaphores`. But implementing `semaphores` for bigger applications is difficult.

**Here comes pthread**

Now thread removes all the difficulties that are faced by `fork`.

1. It doesn't create a separate process.
2. It rather creates few light-weight subtasks which can run almost parallel.
3. They all share same address space & hence no need for any `IPC`.
4. The come with `mutex` which is wonderful for any synchronizations needed even for bigger applications.
5. Thread also don't create any process hence all threads is a part of same process and hence will have same pid.

**Note:** In C++, thread is a part of C++ library, not a system call.

**Note 2:** Boost threads in C++ are much more mature & recommended to use.

*The main idea although is to know that when to use thread & when to use process.*

If you need to create a sub-task which doesn't need to work with some other task but it has to work in isolation, use process; otherwise use thread.

The `exec` family syscalls are different. It uses your **same pid**. Hence if you create an application with 500 lines say, and you get a `exec` call at line number 250, then that `exec` process will be pasted on your whole process and after `exec` call, you program will not resume from 251 line. Also, `exec` calls don't flush your stdio buffers.

**But yes, if you intend to create a separate process, and then use `exec` call to perform that task and then come out, then you are welcome to do it, but remember the IPC to store the output otherwise it is of no use**

For more info on fork click **[here](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html)**

For more info on thread click **[here](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node29.html)**

For boost therad click **[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread.html)**

*@John Zwinck* answer is also good but I know little about `select()` system call but yes it is possible that way too

**Edited:** As @ Jonathan Leffler  pointed

**Editing after a long**: After some years I now never think of using all these SPOOKY libraries or senseless gruesome ways of parallel or should I say SEEMINGLY parallel processing. Enter **coroutines**, the future of CONCURRENT processing. Look at the following Go code. Sure this is possible in C/C++ too. This code would hardly be few milliseconds slower for 7.7 mil rows in database than its C/C++ thread based implementation but sever times more manageable and scalable.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type AirQuality struct {
    // gorm.Model
    // ID      uint   `gorm:"column:id"`
    Index   string `gorm:"column:index"`
    BEN     string `gorm:"column:BEN"`
    CH4     string `gorm:"column:CH4"`
    CO      string `gorm:"column:CO"`
    EBE     string `gorm:"column:EBE"`
    MXY     string `gorm:"column:MXY"`
    NMHC    string `gorm:"column:NMHC"`
    NO      string `gorm:"column:NO"`
    NO2     string `gorm:"column:NO_2"`
    NOX     string `gorm:"column:NOx"`
    OXY     string `gorm:"column:OXY"`
    O3      string `gorm:"column:O_3"`
    PM10    string `gorm:"column:PM10"`
    PM25    string `gorm:"column:PM25"`
    PXY     string `gorm:"column:PXY"`
    SO2     string `gorm:"column:SO_2"`
    TCH     string `gorm:"column:TCH"`
    TOL     string `gorm:"column:TOL"`
    Time    string `gorm:"column:date; type:timestamp"`
    Station string `gorm:"column:station"`
}

func (AirQuality) TableName() string {
    return "AQ"
}

func main() {
    c := generateRowsConcurrent("boring!!")

    for row := range c {
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}

func generateRowsConcurrent(msg string) <-chan []string {
    c := make(chan []string)
    go func() {
        db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "./load_testing_7.6m.db")
        if err != nil {
            panic("failed to connect database")
        }
        defer db.Close()
        rows, err := db.Model(&AirQuality{}).Limit(20).Rows()
        defer rows.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for rows.Next() {
            var aq AirQuality
            db.ScanRows(rows, &aq)
            v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(aq))
            var buf []string
            for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
                buf = append(buf, v.Field(i).String())
            }
            c <- buf
        }

        defer close(c)
    }()
    return c
}
```

Comment: You've not mentioned the bad things about threads — such as you _have_ to synchronize access to all global variables.  Also, the `exec` calls do not create a process; they replace the current process with a different one.  As you point out, the PID remains unchanged.

Comment: Synchronization of access to all the global variables can be done using `Mutex` and that I don't consider a bad thing because `mutex` is easy to use as far as I think. Yes it was a mistake to say `exec` creates a different `process`. I never actually meant that. Thanks to point out.

Comment: IPC does not need to be blocking and "slow."  You can use select/poll/etc with pipes, domain sockets, and more.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar I disagree, first *mutexes* are not the only way to synchronize threads, and most importantly multithreading is hard.

Comment: @JohnZwinck As I have already mentioned, I have little knowledge about `poll` and `select`. But I would still prefer `shared memory` and `semephore`

Comment: And there is no `Fork()` function.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: If you don't know poll or select, you should probably not be answering this question.  Poll and select are time-tested, standard ways of solving the OP's problem on the OP's chosen platforms.

Comment: Thank you. This is really nice. I guess the library `libuv` is more suitable for my purpose.